# Implicitly lazy static members in Swift

Tags: swift, static, swift2, lazy-loading, static-members

I just noticed that `static` members of Swift `structs` are implicitly `lazy`.

For instance, this will only call the `init` once:

```
class Baz {
    init(){
        print("initializing a Baz")
    }
}
struct Foo {
    static let bar = Baz()
}

var z = Foo.bar
z = Foo.bar
```

What's the rationale behind this?

What if I want the opposite behaviour?

Comment: There's some rationale for the choice for global variables being lazy here: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=7. Static members presumably would have similar rationale, except even less reason for the on-startup initialization (i mean, what if you never even used a type, it was just brought in via an import? should all static variables still be initialized regardless of use?)

Comment: (A little late to the party) As far as I can see you are talking about two things: a) the static lazy loading and b) init being called only once. As per b), why would it be called more than once in your code? I don't see any reason, you are accessing the same one thing, just twice. Same one thing means init is called once.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

The `static` property defines a "type property", one that is instantiated once and only once. As you note, this happens lazily, as statics behave like globals. And as [The Swift Programming Language: Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID254) says:

> Global constants and variables are always computed lazily, in a similar manner to [Lazy Stored Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID257). Unlike lazy stored properties, global constants and variables do not need to be marked with the `lazy` modifier.

This implicitly lazy behavior is because, as the [Swift Blog: Files and Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=7) says:

> it allows custom initializers, startup time in Swift scales cleanly with no global initializers to slow it down, and the order of execution is completely predictable.

They consciously designed it that way to avoid unnecessarily delaying the startup of the app.

If you want to instantiate the `static` property at some particular point in your app (rather than deferring it to where it's first used), simply reference this `static` property at that earlier point and the object will be initialized at that time. Given the efforts we put into reducing the latency in starting our apps, you generally wouldn't to want this synchronously during the initial launch of the app, but you can do it wherever you want.

---

Note that unlike `lazy` instance properties, the instantiating of globals and `static` variables is thread-safe.

Comment: In the example "static let cache = NSCache()", is cache initialized at start up time, or, only when "cache is first used" ... ?

Comment: It is instantiated lazily, the first time you use `cache` in your code.